# SQL Query with optional WHERE clause parameter for date range?

Tags: t-sql

I have a procedure that takes, among other things,  start and end date parameters. These two parameters are optional inputs and default to NULL. What I would like to do is modify one of the current `SELECT` statements so that if the start and end dates are supplied it will return only the results between those two dates. I considered just throwing a `CASE WHEN...` in the `WHERE` statement but that that is messy and does not seem right. Is that the appropriate way to deal with this or is there something more efficient?

Existing `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT  do.OrdrNmbr AS 'Order Number',
        mb.BOLNmbr AS 'BOL Number',
        do.DlvryDt  AS 'Deliver Date',
        mh.Text3 AS 'Truck',
        do.DlvrdQntty AS 'Gallons Delivered',
        ba.BANme AS 'Carier Business Associate'
FROM dbo.DeliveryOrder AS do WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.ManifestBOL AS mb WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON do.OrdrNmbr = mb.OrdrNmbr
INNER JOIN dbo.BusinessAssociate AS ba WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON do.CrrrBAID = ba.BAID
INNER JOIN SRA.dbo.MovementDocument as md WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON md.MvtDcmntExtrnlDcmntNbr = 'DOD' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, mb.OrdrNmbr)
INNER JOIN SRA.dbo.MovementHeader AS mh WITH (NOLOCK)
   ON mh.MvtHdrMvtDcmntID = md.MvtDcmntID
WHERE mb.OrdrNmbr = @OrderNumber;
```

and the start/end dates would run against `do.DlvryDt`.

P.S. I know the table/column names are horrid but this is a 3rd party application the query is running against.

Comment: (1) Please be careful with `AS 'alias'` syntax - this is deprecated (see https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases). (2) Be careful declaring types like `VARCHAR` without length (see https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). (3) Be careful with `NOLOCK` all over the place. This is not a magical turbo button, and can lead to incorrect results in a variety of ways.

Comment: Did not know the `AS` syntax was deprecated thanks. The `NOLOCK` is required in our environment due to the high CRUD requests being hit and is in place per our DBA. I, personally, try to stay away from it but such is life.

Comment: It's not the `AS`, it's the single quotes around aliases that's deprecated.

Comment: @Matthew at the very least, you should use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` at the top, instead of `NOLOCK` littered throughout the query. At the very least, when your DBA learns about snapshot isolation, it's one change instead of `<number of tables in query>`.

Comment: Also do you need to support the case where only the start date is supplied, or only the end date? Or is both or none?

Comment: I need to support the case when no start and end date is supplied or both are supplied. If the user inputs a start date the .net app forces them to put in an end date and vice versa. Also if the quote marks are being dropped how does one create a multi word alias that has spaces in it?

Comment: @Matthew `[like this]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested Binaya Regmi's answer and it worked but I also ran across a blog posting that helped me develop, what I think, is a better solution.

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

I added

```
AND (do.DlvryDt >= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
AND (do.DlvryDt <= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
```

to the where clause and all works well.

Comment: Why do you think that's different from Binaya's answer? Should boil down to the same execution plan. Personally I think the better approach is one where you build dynamic SQL based on the presence of parameters - this has the least chance of going horribly wrong due to different parameters, and you can use OPTION (RECOMPILE) to prevent wonkiness due to different parameter values too.

Comment: OR is often less performant

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your start date and end date are compared against DlvryDt in DeliveryOrder table, I suggest to use a very low date value for start date and a very high date value for end date in cases where these date variables are null. Please see following query.

```
SELECT  do.OrdrNmbr AS 'Order Number',
        mb.BOLNmbr AS 'BOL Number',
        do.DlvryDt  AS 'Deliver Date',
        mh.Text3 AS 'Truck',
        do.DlvrdQntty AS 'Gallons Delivered',
        ba.BANme AS 'Carier Business Associate'
FROM dbo.DeliveryOrder AS do WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.ManifestBOL AS mb WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON do.OrdrNmbr = mb.OrdrNmbr
INNER JOIN dbo.BusinessAssociate AS ba WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON do.CrrrBAID = ba.BAID
INNER JOIN SRA.dbo.MovementDocument as md WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON md.MvtDcmntExtrnlDcmntNbr = 'DOD' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, mb.OrdrNmbr)
INNER JOIN SRA.dbo.MovementHeader AS mh WITH (NOLOCK)
   ON mh.MvtHdrMvtDcmntID = md.MvtDcmntID
WHERE mb.OrdrNmbr = @OrderNumber
and do.DlvryDt >= ISNULL(@StartDate, '19000101')
and do.DlvryDt < ISNULL(dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate), '21000101');
```

Comment: Couple of things: (1) this may not optimize so well if a plan is first generated for the dates being populated, then subsequent queries don't use them, and vice versa. (2) Should actually use `< DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)` to not lose any data from the end day after midnight.